# Dynamic Scramble Game using Unity C# and PHP (Mysql as database)

Tags: c#, php, mysql, unity-game-engine

I have here codes that scramble declared words based on [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8_JR2b_VnQ) video.Below are the codes that depends on array of words I declared on Unity Editor. The problem is I want it to be dynamic, like it will fetch words into database. I wrote a code in php that retrieves data from db and a code on csharp that reads the php via WWW method. I can't merge this two process- scramble words and getting words from db, Please help me guys, Thank you.

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rimhp.png) is my Unity setup for scramble word. as you can see I attached WordScrambe.cs to Core Gameobject and declared 2 words-"YES" and "YOURS".

CharObject.cs

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CharObject : MonoBehaviour {
public char character;
public Text text;
public Image image;
public RectTransform rectTransform;
public int index;

[Header("Appearance")]
public Color normalColor;
public Color selectedColor; 

bool isSelected= false;

public CharObject Init(char c)
{
    character = c;
    text.text = c.ToString ();
    gameObject.SetActive (true); 
    return this;
}

public void Select()
{
    isSelected = !isSelected;
    image.color = isSelected ? selectedColor : normalColor;
    if (isSelected) {
        WordScramble.main.Select (this);
    } else {
        WordScramble.main.UnSelect();
    }
}
}
```

WordScramble.cs

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    [System.Serializable]
    public class Word
    {
        public string word; 
        [Header("leave empty if you want randomized")]
        public string desiredRandom; 
    
        public string GetString() 
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty (desiredRandom))
            {
                return desiredRandom;
            }
            string result = word;
    
    
            while (result==word) 
            {
                result = ""; 
                List<char> characters = new List<char> (word.ToCharArray ()); 
                while (characters.Count > 0) 
                {
                    int indexChar = Random.Range (0, characters.Count - 1); 
                    //Debug.Log(characters[indexChar]);
                    result += characters [indexChar]; 
                    Debug.Log(word);
                    characters.RemoveAt (indexChar);
                }
            }
    
            return result;
            
        }// end of Getstring Method
    }
    
    public class WordScramble : MonoBehaviour {
    
        public Word[] words;
    
        [Header("UI REFERENCE")]
        public CharObject prefab;
        public Transform container;
        public float space;
        public float lerpSpeed=5;
    
        List<CharObject> charobjects = new List<CharObject>();
        CharObject firstSelected;
    
        public int currentWord;
        public static WordScramble main;
    
        void Awake()
        {
            main = this;
        }
    
    
    
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start () {
            ShowScramble (currentWord);
        }
        
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update ()
        {
            RepositionObject ();
        }
    
        void RepositionObject()
        {
            if (charobjects.Count==0) {
                return;
            }
            float center = (charobjects.Count -1) / 2;
            for (int i = 0; i < charobjects.Count; i++)
            {
                charobjects[i].rectTransform.anchoredPosition= Vector2.Lerp(charobjects[i].rectTransform.anchoredPosition, new Vector2((i- center)* space,  0), lerpSpeed* Time.deltaTime) ;
                charobjects [i].index = i;
            }
    
        }
        //show a random word to the screen
        public void ShowScramble()
        {
            ShowScramble (Random.Range (0, words.Length - 1)); 
        }
        //<summary>Show word from collection with desired index
        public void ShowScramble(int index)
        {
            charobjects.Clear ();
            foreach (Transform child in container) {
                Destroy (child.gameObject);
            }
            //Words Finished
            if (index > words.Length - 1) {
                Debug.LogError ("index out of range, please enter range betwen 0-" + (words.Length - 1).ToString ());
                return;
            }
    
            char[] chars = words [index].GetString ().ToCharArray ();
            foreach (char c in chars) 
            {
                CharObject clone = Instantiate (prefab.gameObject).GetComponent<CharObject> ();
                clone.transform.SetParent (container);
    
                charobjects.Add (clone.Init (c));
            }
    
            currentWord = index;
        }
        public void Swap(int indexA, int indexB)
        {
            CharObject tmpA = charobjects [indexA];
    
            charobjects[indexA] = charobjects [indexB];
            charobjects[indexB] = tmpA;
    
            charobjects [indexA].transform.SetAsLastSibling ();
            charobjects [indexB].transform.SetAsLastSibling ();
    
            CheckWord ();
        }
    
        public void Select(CharObject charObject)
        {
            if (firstSelected) 
            {
                Swap (firstSelected.index, charObject.index);
    
                //Unselect
    
                firstSelected.Select();
                charObject.Select();
    
            } else {
                firstSelected = charObject;
            }
        }
        public void UnSelect()
        {
            firstSelected = null;
        }
        public void CheckWord()
        {
            StartCoroutine (CoCheckWord());
        }
        IEnumerator CoCheckWord()
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds (0.5f);
            string word = "";
            foreach (CharObject charObject in charobjects)
            {
                word += charObject.character;
            }
            if (word == words [currentWord].word) {
                currentWord++;
                ShowScramble (currentWord);
    
    
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Below are the codes for retrieving data from db using PHP and passing data to unity.

read.php

```
    <?php
    include '../../connection.php';
    
    $query=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM words");
    while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
            
        echo $get=$fetch["words"];
        echo ",";
    }
    
    ?>
```

fetch.cs-I attached this to Main Camera on Unity Editor for the mean time.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class fetch : MonoBehaviour {
    
        
        public string[] dbWords;
    
         IEnumerator Start(){
            WWW words=new WWW("http://localhost/bootstrap/android/v2/read.php");
            yield return words;
            string wordsDataString=words.text;
            print(wordsDataString);
            dbWords=wordsDataString.Split(',');
        }
    }
```

In short I want to make a scramble game in unity that the words of it depends on the database . I have the process of word scramble(but static) and retrieving data from database but not connected to scramble game I made, means my project is not yet dynamic, I'm sorry for uncleared explanations.
Thank you and more power! :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO!

It is not entirely clear where your problem lies, however I think you mean to say that you are not receiving a result from your database?

Let's start by moving your Database logic to a separate class for good practice.
Also the Start Method of a MonoBehaviour is of returntype void, and not an IENumerator. You need an IENumerator, which you can call with StartCoroutine.

Create a seperate class like below

```
public static class NetworkManager
{
    public static IEnumerator Fetch(Action<string[]> callback)
    {
        WWW words=new WWW("http://localhost/bootstrap/android/v2/read.php");
        yield return words;
        string wordsDataString=words.text;
        print(wordsDataString);
        var result = wordsDataString.Split(',');

        callback?.Invoke(result);
    }
}
```

I cannot test your code that you had in your Fetch method because you are using it locally, but let's assume it works for now.

Notice the callback as a parameter. 
This allows you to register an action that will fire once your database call is completed.

It is invoked in the last line of the method. 
You can then call the method like this:

```
public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    StartCoroutine(NetworkManager.Fetch( (words) => 
    {
        // Do something with the words!
        SomeMethod(words);
    });
}
```

As soon as the Coroutine finishes, any code between the brackets is executed. In this case "SomeMethod" accepting words as a parameter will fire.

I hope this clarifies and answers your question!

Comment: I wish to make a scramble word game that the words of it will depend on database for it to be dynamic. I can upload my built apk for static scramble word game if ever. my database is totally not connected yet on my game